# C++ expected type-specifier

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

#### Background

I am in the middle of a [project](https://bitbucket.org/nwehr/kick) writing stl-like containers for the Arduino. So far I have successfully written deque, vector, and string.

#### Problem

I have run into a problem with the `map` container. For some reason, in the `map::insert()` method, the compiler is telling me that it is expecting a type specifier. I have included all the code related to the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// pair
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<typename K, typename V>
class pair {
public:
    pair( const K& key, const V& val )
    : _key_( key )
    , _val_( val )
    {}

    pair( const pair& p )
    : _key_( p.key() )
    , _val_( p.val() )
    {}

    virtual ~pair(){}

    K& key(){
        return _key_;
    }

    V& val(){
        return _val_;
    }

private:
    K _key_;
    V _val_;
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// map
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<typename K, typename V>
class map {
public:
    map()
    : _size_( 0 )
    , _items_( 0 )
    {}

    virtual ~map(){
        for( int i = 0; i < _size_; ++i )
            delete _items_[i];

        free( _items_ );

    }

    void insert( const pair<K,V>& p ){
        _items_ = reinterpret_cast<kick::pair<K,V>**>( realloc( _items_, (sizeof( void* ) * (++_size_)) ) );
        _items_[_size_ - 1] = new pair( p ); //error: expected type-specifier
    }

    V& operator[]( const K& key ){
        for( int i = 0; i < _size_; ++i ){
            if( _items_[i].key() == key )
                return _items_[i].val();

        }

    }

private:
    int _size_;
    pair<K,V>** _items_;

};
```

Answer (score 3):

`pair` is just a template, not a type. The compiler is expecting the template parameters, which in this case are types. This is, it is expecting your line to be:

```
_items_[_size_ - 1] = new pair<K,V>( p );
```

No, it cannot deduce the template parameters; this only works for template functions, not types.

Comment: ...which is why the standard library includes http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair.

Comment: @NateKohl Yes, the Standard Library includes several utility functions like `make_pair` for this exact reason. Though it would not help in this case, even if OP could use the Standard Library (which I think is not the case).

Answer (score 1):

`new pair<K,V>( p )` is what it wants there.

For myself, I'd implement a flat-map on top of `vector` so I didn't have to do memory management in it.  An advantage of this is that you can remove a level of indirection.  (Indirection is the performance killer).

Another thought is to have a high-water sorting mark, where things before the sorting mark are sorted, and things after it are jumbled.  This can give you fewer comparisons when the container gets large.  But first get your flat-map working.

Comment: I've never heard of high-water sorting, I'll have to look into that. The reason I'm not building `map` on top of `vector` is because I want each of the container types to be independent of each other. There may be a time in the future when a programmer may only want to include a single container type in their project.

Comment: @Nathan Then write a "managed array" and have `vector` be a naked wrapper around it, and `map` be a slightly more complex one.  Writing memory management stuff twice means twice as many bugs, and half as much performance increase from optimization.